# Concatening files using streams

Tags: node.js, file, stream

My app generates several files in parallel that I finally have to concat before serving it to the user.
Some of these can be big (>10M).

In order to achieve this, I have create 2 routines, one for handling the set of files to process and one for appending the content of a file to a destination one. Everything works fine on small/medium size files, but on large ones, the content is truncated...

```
function copyFileContent(ws,rs){
    let errorDetected=false;
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if(rs && ws){
            ws.on('error',(err)=>{
                errorDetected=true;
                return reject();
            });
            ws.on('close',()=>{
                if(!errorDetected){
                    resolve(); // -> need to wait for large files...
                } // Else reject has already occured...
            });
            rs.pipe(ws);
        } else reject();
    })
}

async function mergeFiles(dest, files){
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        let w=fs.createWriteStream(dest,{flags: 'a', encoding: 'utf-8'});
        let r=fs.createReadStream(files[i]);
        await copyFileContent(w,r);
    }
}
```

After some investigation, I have doublechecked that the close event on the writeStream (ws) was not a consequence of an error (which could justify that the content is truncated).
I finally added some delay by replacing the 'resolve()' statement by setTimeout(()=>{resolve()},3000);
And obviously allowing more time for the system (OS=Windows 10) to indeed write to file fixes the issue. But I don't understand why ! What is happening under the scene ? How to avoid such behaviour. I need to make sure that when the 'close' event occurs, then the file is indeed fully populated.

Can anyone help me finding my bug or misunderstanding on streams ?
Thx

Comment: Actually this works as expected. One of the input files was itself the output of a writeStream, which unfortunately was not properly closed. Cascading streams is definitely a great feature, but needs caution when piping and doing things in parallel. My 2 cents :)